# My analysis give me different result than I excepted (forecasting data analysis using ARIMA model in python)

Tags: python, time-series, data-analysis, forecasting, arima

This is my Python code using the `ARIMA` model in Python. (BTW, I never used this model before; I only needed it for my thesis research) when I ran this code, I expected some changes in forecasting data, but it changes only started and stayed the same until the end. If it's not right, can someone tell me why it's not right, or do I have to use a different type of model for forecasting for data time analysis?

This is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

# Load the bus time data from CSV
data = pd.read_csv('bus_time_data.csv')

# Select the 'BusTime' column as the target variable
target_variable = data['BusTime']

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_data = target_variable.iloc[:-250]  # Use all except the last 2000 data points for training
test_data = target_variable.iloc[-250:]  # Use the last 2000 data points for testing

# Fit the ARIMA model to the training data
model = ARIMA(train_data, order=(2, 0, 0))  # Specify the order (p, d, q) of the ARIMA model
model_fit = model.fit()

# Perform forecasting for the test data
forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=250)  # Forecast the next 1000 time points

# Plot the actual and forecasted bus time data
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(test_data, label='Actual')
plt.plot(forecast, label='Forecast')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Bus Time')
plt.title('ARIMA Forecast of Bus Time')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# # Scatter plot of actual vs forecasted bus time data
# plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
# plt.scatter(test_data.index, test_data, label='Actual', color='blue')
# plt.scatter(test_data.index, forecast, label='Forecast', color='red')
# plt.xlabel('Index')
# plt.ylabel('Bus Time')
# plt.title('Scatter Plot of Actual vs Forecasted Bus Time')
# plt.legend()
# plt.show()
```

This is csv file example(there are more than 200k data, so I only share part of it)

```
index   DateTime    BusTime
1   5:49    60
2   5:48    240
3   5:57    60
4   5:58    120
5   6:00    180
6   6:03    180
7   6:06    60
8   6:06    240
9   6:13    120
10  6:11    240
11  6:19    120
12  6:21    60
13  6:20    120
14  6:18    60
15  6:18    240
16  6:25    240
17  6:29    60
18  6:28    240
19  6:37    60
20  6:38    180
21  6:35    240
22  6:39    60
23  5:53    240
24  6:02    240
25  5:56    240
26  6:04    240
27  6:08    300
28  6:03    240
29  6:11    60
```